# Spring Kafka outboundChannelAdapter's control does not return back in the integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

After a messsage is sent, it gets published to Kafka topic but the Message from `KafkaSuccessTransformer` does not return back to the REST controller. I am trying to return the message as-is if sent successfully but nothing after Kafka handler seems to be invoked.

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface MyGateway<String, Message<?>> {
  @Gateway(requestChannel = "enrollChannel")
  Message<?> sendMsg(@Payload String payload);
}
------------------------

@RestController
public class Controller {
  MyGateway<String, Message<?>> myGateway;

  @PostMapping
  public Message<?> send(@RequestBody String request) throws Exception {
    Message<?> resp = myGateway.sendMsg(request);
    log.info("I am back"); // control doesn't come to this point
    return resp;
  }
}
--------------------------

@Component
public class MyIntegrationFlow {
  KafkaSuccessTransformer stransformer;

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel enrollChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel kafkaSuccessChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow enrollIntegrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("enrollChannel")
        //another transformer which turns the string to Message<?>
        .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate) //kafkaTemplate has the necesssary config
            .topic("topic1")
            .messageKey(messageKeyFunction -> messageKeyFunction.getHeaders()
                .get("key1")
            .sendSuccessChannel("kafkaSuccessChannel"));
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow successfulKafkaSends() {
    return f -> IntegrationFlows.from("kafkaSuccessChannel").transform(stransformer);
  }
}
--------------

@Component
public class KafkaSuccessTransformer {

  @Transformer
  public Message<?> transform(Message<?> message) {
    log.info("Message is sent to Kafka");
    return message; //control comes here but does not return to REST controller
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Channel adapters are for one-way traffic; there is no result.</strike>

Add a publishSubscribe channel with two subflows; the second one can be just a bridge to nowhere - `.bridge()` ends the flow. It will then return the outbound message to the gateway.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows

Per Artem:

Something is off in the configuration or code. The logic is like this: `processSendResult(message, producerRecord, sendFuture, getSendSuccessChannel());`. Then: `getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage(message)`. So, the `replyChannel` header is present in this "success" message. Therefore that `transform(stransformer)` should really produce its return to the replyChannel for a gateway in the beginning. Only the problem could be in the `KafkaSuccessTransformer` code where it does not copy request message headers for reply message. Please, share its whole code.

Comment: Something is off in the configuration or code. The logic is like this: `processSendResult(message, producerRecord, sendFuture, getSendSuccessChannel());`. Then: `getMessageBuilderFactory().fromMessage(message)` . So, the `replyChannel` header is present in this "success" message. Therefore that `transform(stransformer)` should really produce its return to the `replyChannel` for a gateway in the beginning. Only the problem could be in the `KafkaSuccessTransformer` code where it does not copy request message headers for reply message. Please, share its whole code.

Comment: Oh sorry; I didn't notice the sendSuccessChannel; deleting this. @ArtemBilan perhaps add an answer?

Comment: @ArtemBilan yes, I was missing the the `replyChannel` header.
Thank you for your time and an awesome project!

Comment: Good. Please, accept this Gary's answer to let everyone to know that we have a solution over here.